# Initialize a static const array member of class in main(...) and not globally?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static, constants

Suppose `class Myclass  { private: static const int myarray[2]; }`

If I wanted to initialize `myarray` I should put the following statement in global scope:

`const int Myclass::myarray[2] = {1,1};`

What should I do If I want to initialize my array in main() (at some **runtime** calculated values eg at `{n1, n2}` where `n1` and `n2` are values calculated at runtime in main() based on the command line arguments)

Comment: one man's const is another man's variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing much you can do.

You could create a member function that would initialize the values, and call it. But, if it's `static`, `private` and `const` - then you can't even do that and out of options.

You cannot *initialize* a `static` member at run-time, you cannot access a `private` member from outside of class (unless you make friends), and you cannot change a `const` member once initialized.

If you give up `const`, then you can change it. You still have to initialize at global scope, but you can change values.

Note that as long as its `private`, you won't be able to access it from `main`, but you can write a wrapper function member to do that for you (or make it `public`).

Comment: You are right, I decided to change `private` to `public` (won't be a big deal) and dropped `const` (won't be a big deal too). Modify your answer (based on your previous comment) so I can accept it